# Can I qsub without source .bash_profile

Tags: linux, shell, cluster-computing, bash, qsub

When I submit a bunch of jobs using qsub, the qsub will source the .bash_profile at first. So how can I qsub a job without source .bash_profile firstly.

Comment: Why is it important for you to avoid loading the bash_profile?

Comment: I want to write a qsub script for public use, but maybe the bash_profile or bashrc of some people's local env. will conflict with the qsub job.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a number of different `qsub` commands, associated with different batch systems.  It would be useful to tell us which batch system you're using.

As I recall, most such systems set one or more environment variables that you can test in your `.bash_profile`.  The systems I've used either set `$ENVIRONMENT` to `"BATCH"`, or set `$PBS_ENVIRONMENT` to `"PBS_BATCH"`.  (Those may be obsolete; check your documentation.)

You could modify your `.bash_profile` to do something like this:

```
if [ "$ENVIRONMENT" != "BATCH" ] ; then
    # existing code here
fi
```

So your `.bash_profile` is still sourced, but it doesn't do anything if it's running in a batch environment.

This is easy to modify so *some* commands are still executed.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thanks. In my case, a successful run of the `qsub` command in interactive mode printed some stuff that hinted at the "pbs" being modified. Upon doing `echo $PBS_ENVIRONMENT`, I got `PBS_INTERACTIVE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can figure out how to pass arguments to bash itself, the one you're looking for is `--noprofile`.  But I'm not familiar with qsub, and a quick glance at the manual for it didn't clue me in on how to do this.  Can you specify what shell your job runs under somehow?

Comment: qsub has one option -S 
"The -S option allows users to specify the program (usually a shell) that will be invoked to process the script of the  batch  job."
Maybe I can use "qsub -S /bin/bash --noprofile", but the qsub cannot recognize the space beween /bin/bash and --noprofile.

Comment: Did you try `qsub -S '/bin/bash --noprofile'`? (using quotes to make the argument to -S be just one string?  I am not certain it will work, but it may.